# How to turn off Divs that aren't selected in the array? Javascript in Shopify

Tags: javascript, for-loop, shopify, toggle, liquid

so my current code works in the Nav to allow that button that's being looped with a matching index to toggle on and off each div. I don't want these divs to toggle, I want only the corresponding div to show and all the others display: none.  Please advise

Thank you!

```
  function showDiv(index) {
let one = document.getElementById('shopify-section-track_order_details');
let two = document.getElementById('shopify-section-returns_exchanges_details');
let three = document.getElementById('shopify-section-contact_us_details');
let four = document.getElementById('shopify-section-order_status_details');
let five = document.getElementById('shopify-section-shipping_returns_details');
let six = document.getElementById('shopify-section-corporate_details');
let seven = document.getElementById('shopify-section-product_help_details');
let eight = document.getElementById('shopify-section-ambassador_details');
let nine = document.getElementById('shopify-section-FAQ_details');

let arrHelp = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine];

let el = arrHelp[index - 1];
    if (el.style.display != "block") {
        el.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        el.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

the link is in Shopify liquid calling the function like:

```
    {% for block in section.blocks %}  
          <a id="pageLink" onclick="showDiv({{ forloop.index }})" >
            {{ block.settings.button }}
            <i id="navArrow{{ forloop.index }}" class="fad fa-chevron-right navArrow" style="float: right"></i>
          </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toggleDiv(index) {
    const $target = document.querySelectorAll('[id*=shopify-section-]')[index];
    $target.classList.toggle('hide');
}

toggleDiv(1);
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
}

#test {
 display: flex;
}

#test > div {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #323232;
  color: #e2e2e2;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <div id="shopify-section-1">1</div>
    <div id="shopify-section-2">2</div>
    <div id="shopify-section-3">3</div>
    <div id="shopify-section-4">4</div>
    <div id="shopify-section-5">5</div>
    <div id="shopify-section-6">6</div>
    <div id="shopify-section-7">7</div>
    <div id="shopify-section-8">8</div>
    <div id="shopify-section-9">9</div>
    <div id="shopify-section-10">10</div>
</div>
```